# UISearchController with UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm looking to create a UISearchController on my ViewController that contains a UITableView (not UITableViewController). I am having 2 warnings and a crash, and unsure if they're related - but do know that one of my issues is the warning

```
'Imcompatiable pointers types sending UITableView to parameter of type UIViewController.'
```

Obviously it's because I'm trying to set up the searchResultsController to my tableView on my UIViewController rather then a UITableViewController like so:

```
   self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.myTableView];
```

with self.myTableView being the UITableView, how would I go about fixing this? Would I have to turn my tableView into a UITableViewController to get this to work right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your setup, you should be passing self, not self.myTableView.

Comment: Ah right thanks! Now for some reason when I click in the searchbar my viewcontroller goes black (besides nav bar) and I get this error "Attempt to present <UISearchController: 0x14e522fa0> on <SalesViewController: 0x14e61a160> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: Nevermind fixed it, apparently you have to pass in nil and not self if you plan on having the view act as the controller

Answer (score 5):

The initWithSearchResultsController method expects a view controller. In my experience, it can be either UIViewController or UITableViewController wherever you want to show your filtered(searched) results.

In your case, I think, you are trying to display the filtered result in the same view controller which holds your tableView. So, the following should get rid of the error you are getting-

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
```

However, you also probably have to set the datasource for the filtered table to be self.